# How do I get the value of an Enum, if I don't know the class at compile time?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums

I'm trying to do the following:

```
Class<?> cls = unknownClass;
if(cls.isEnum()){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass = (Class<? extends Enum<?>>) cls;
    Object val = Enum.valueOf(enumClass, "NAME1");
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method valueOf(Class<T>, String) of type Enum<E> is 
not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#5-of ? extends Enum<?>>, String). 
The inferred type capture#5-of ? extends Enum<?> is not a valid substitute for 
the bounded parameter <T extends Enum<T>>
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Given that the cast won't *really* be checking things, I'd go with the completely raw version:

```
if (cls.isEnum()){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Object val = Enum.valueOf(cls, "NAME1");
}
```

That seems to work. Complete example:

```
public class Test
{
    enum Foo
    {
        BAR, BAZ
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class cls = Foo.class;

        if (cls.isEnum())
        {        
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Object value = Enum.valueOf(cls, "BAR");
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dacwe: Well it works on *my* compiler - but you haven't said in what *way* it doesn't work. I'll show a short but complete example...

Comment: Ah, sorry, it does not compile. `Class<?> cls = SomeEnum.class; Object val = Enum.valueOf(cls, "NAME1");` and I get a simular `Bound mismatch` as the asker.

Comment: @dacwe: You hadn't shown us the declaration of `cls`. Just change it to the raw type `Class` instead of `Class<?>`. See my edit for a complete example.

Comment: (And if you can't change the declaration for `cls`, use `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz = cls;` and then use `clazz` instead.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you have two `?` and they could be different and they have to be the same.

You either have to use a non generic of declare a generic type like

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T val(Class<T> cls) {
    if(cls.isEnum()) { // is redundant when the compiler checks this.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<T> enumClass = (Class<T>) cls;
        T val = Enum.valueOf(enumClass, "NAME1");
        return val;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, calling this method is a bit of a nightmare as well. ;)

Comment: `T` is defined as a class which extends `Enum<T>`  This is due to the Enum's cumbersome/recursive declaration of `public class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`

Comment: @Peter: yeah but it's just going to be completely erased since the caller can't interact with T.

Comment: As you wrote, how *do* I call the method? :)

Comment: You can simply call `val(MyEnum.class)` however the compiler is likely to get confused trying to determine the return type as its not bound by one of the arguments so you end up writing `MyClass.<MyEnum,MyEnum>val(MyEnum.class)`  In a more sensible example, you wouldn't need to check isEnum() and V=T and its much simpler.

Comment: Simpified the example, but makes the check redundnat.

Comment: Exactly, but how do I get it to work with a unknown `Class<?>`?

Comment: You have to cast it to `(Class)`

Answer (score 5):

`Class.getEnumConstants` will give all the enums, which you can then find the one you are interested in.

Modifying Jon's code:

```
public class Test {
    private enum Foo {
        BAR, BAZ
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> cls = Foo.class;

        if (cls.isEnum()) { 
            for (Object constant : cls.getEnumConstants()) { 
                Enum<?> enumConstant = (Enum<?>)constant;
                if (enumConstant.name().equals("BAR")) {
                    System.out.println(constant);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Java SE 8, you'll possibly be able do something clever with a lambda and abstracted control flow.

Note:

- Reflection is *almost* always a really bad idea.
- No need for unchecked warning or suppression of those valid warnings.
- No need for rawtypes (which ever spelling and semantics) warning or suppression of those valid warnings.
- No need for an unfounded rant.
- No need to downvote this answer.

Comment: I like that if I don't know the enum type at compile time, this solution won't throw a compiler warning. I can have just an instance of type foo and call fooInstance.getClass() and use that for cls.

Answer (score 1):

Using raw type is good. While Java was reluctant to add raw type, it has been proven to be necessary and indispensable, beyond backward compatibility issues.

Without raw types, to solve your problem in a theoretically perfect way, Java has to be way more complicated. It probably needs a type-variable-variable. At that point, the code is no longer to please the humans, it is to please the machines. (We are probably already at this point, considering all the generics code that are impossible to understand)

Answer (score -1):

```
    class EnumValues<P extends Enum<P>>
    {
        public static <P extends Enum<P>> P [] getValues( Class<P> keyType)
        {
            return keyType.getEnumConstants();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    Class cls = Thread.State.class;
    for( Enum en : EnumValues.getValues( cls)) 
        System.out.println( en.name());
```

Comment: Calling a generic method with raw types is a bit on the naughty side. Effectively there's an unchecked cast there. Recent compilers will give you warnings (heed them!). (Not my downvote, btw.)