# Proving Enum classes are Enum classes when they're passed or stored

Tags: java, generics, types, enums

If I pass to a method, or store in a variable, a collection of classes that I know are all Enums (ideally guaranteed, but I don't mind casting), is there a way to let the compiler know they are enum classes, in order to use methods like `values()`, `EnumSet.allOf()`, etc?  I.e., I'm looking at cases where I cannot refer to the names of the Enum classes directly.

I believe this is not possible, but wanted to verify.

An example might look something like this:

```
enumClasses.stream()
        .map(eclass -> EnumSet.allOf(eclass))
        ... more here...
```

but I don't see a way to prove in the declaration of enumClasses (as variable or parameter) that it's only enums.

**Examples:** Some cases I tried that did not work using `Class<? extends Enum<?>>>`

```
    List<? extends Class<? extends Enum<?>>> enums = List.of(MyEnum.class); 
    enums.forEach(eclass -> EnumSet.allOf(eclass)); // error here.
```

or

```
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass = MyEnum.class;
    EnumSet.allOf(enumClass); // error here.
    enumClass.values(); // error here.
```

I also tried creating this helper-method signature:

```
static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet myValues(Class<E> iEnumClass) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(iEnumClass);
}
```

and the method compiles fine, but I have the same problems as above when I try to *call* the method (unless I call that method directly with the class-name, like `myValues(MyEnum.class)`)

Comment: `List<? extends Class<? extends Enum<?>>>` might work.

Comment: You can look at the definition of `EnumSet` to see how to do this with generics.  I'm not sure what your actual requirements are though.  `Class EnumSet<E extends Enum<E>>`

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I don't think so, or at least I can't get it to work, see counterexamples I've added.

Comment: @markspace, I want to collect the values of several enums passed to a method.  (The enum objects themselves implement an additional interface for further processing downstream, but for now I just wish to collect values, given a Class object where I know that the class is an Enum.)

Comment: This [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8704051/411282) gives a potential workaround, though it requires a wrapper class **and** the wrapper class must be specialized to any additional interfaces I wish for the enum to implement.  (I.e., if I want to know that the values I'm getting are of type `MyEnumInterface` I'd need one wrapper class for that case, rather than a wrapper that can be used generically for other cases like this.)

Comment: (I don't need the `valueOfSearchName` or the index, but the wrapper supports adding a `values()` method that returns a `List<E>`. or `List<MyEnum>`)

Comment: Sorry for the noise, but even with the wrapper it's hard, because I can't call the constructor or static factory using an object typed with my Interface, **even** if the wrapper class is specialized to that interface with `&`.

Comment: "Something like the following doesn't work": doesn't work how?

Comment: @user207421, if I define the variable that way, I cannot use methods that require enums, like `values()` or `EnumSet.allof()`.  I expanded the examples below.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know that this is not sufficient. "Doesn't work" and "I cannot" are not problem descriptions.

Comment: Thanks, @user207421, I've cleaned up the text a bit to clarify that the cases below were the examples showing that that type declaration was not sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried using an interface? If you give all of your enums a common interface, you simplify your problem greatly.

Comment: @davidalayachew, they do have a common interface, but the problem is that when I have an object of type `MyInterface` I can't call methods like `values()` `EnumSet.allOf()` on that object even though I know it will be an enum.  You can't, for instance, say `interface MyInterface extends Enum`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in a [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5262096/411282) that there's a method on `Class` called `getEnumConstants()`

(It simply returns null if it's not an enum, but in my case I know that it is.  `isEnum()` is also provided if needed.)

```
List<Class<?>> enumClasses; // or List<Class<? extends MyInterface>>
enumClasses.stream()
    .map(Class::getEnumConstants)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    ...
```

This doesn't directly solve the question as I posed it in the title, but it does solve the use-case I had, which was to collect the values of several same-interface enums.

Comment: @Holger There are a variety of different enum Classes being passed in.  MyEnum1, MyEnum2, ... if you like.  If it were just the one, I'd spell out MyEnum.class in the code where I need the values.

Comment: But then, you can’t declare your list as `List<Class<? extends MyEnum>>`

Comment: @Holger, now I see your point, and it was a mistake (edited now).  At that spot in the code sample, I meant to refer to an interface that the different enums implement, not a particular concrete enum class.  If the enums don't implement a shared interface (or even if they do) it would be fine to change to `List<Class<?>>` or it could be `List<Class<? extends MyInterface>>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is with the bound `<E extends Enum<E>>`, which exists on both `EnumSet.allOf()` (as well as the `EnumSet` class itself) and your `myValues()` method. Basically, you need a "list of classes, each of which inherits `Enum` of itself", and there is no way to express that in Java.

With `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`, you are giving up the requirement that the class inherit `Enum` of itself, so it's possible to put some invalid values in there. For example, someone could put `Enum.class` itself (the class object representing the `Enum` class itself) in there. Or, someone could take an enum with an enum constant that implements custom methods; such an enum constant would be an instance of an anonymous subclass of the enum. So running `.getClass()` on this would give you a `Class` which is a subclass of `Enum`, but it is not the actual class of the enum that you want.

If you want to hold a list of enum classes safely, you would probably have to define your own custom class `ListOfEnumClasses` or something like that. The `add()` method would be generic and enforce the relationship on the type variable, like

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> void add(Class<E> clazz) { }
```

Internally you might still hold it as a `List<Class<? extends Enum<?>>`, but you would not expose this variable to the outside. To pass one of the elements to something like `EnumSet.allOf()` internally, you would probably have to cast it to a raw type to turn off generics, like: `EnumSet.allOf((Class) eclass)`

Comment: The key for me here is the last line:`EnumSet.allOf` won't complain if you cast the argument to raw `Class`.  A holder-class could help guarantee its arguments fit the invariant, but if it returned an object to pass to another method it would have to "regress" to `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` (still requiring the raw cast or the reflection in my own answer) since the various objects have different `E`.